# How to pass data to custom Vue Extension in TipTap?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tiptap

I'm trying to pass data to a custom vue component that gets rendered inside the `tiptap editor`. I can pass `default` properties but assigning reactive values to it doesn't seem to work.

This is the **`tiptap-node-extension.js`** file:

```
import {Node, mergeAttributes} from '@tiptap/core'
import {VueNodeViewRenderer} from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import Component from '@/views/components/vue-component.vue'

export default Node.create({
    parseHTML() {
        return [{ tag: 'vue-component' }]
    },
    renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
        return ['vue-component', mergeAttributes(HTMLAttributes)]
    },
    addNodeView() {
        return VueNodeViewRenderer(Component)
    },
})
```

the `script setup` portion of the `editor` component:

```
<script setup>
import {useEditor, EditorContent, BubbleMenu} from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import {Underline} from "@tiptap/extension-underline";
import {TextAlign} from "@tiptap/extension-text-align";
import {Link} from "@tiptap/extension-link";
import VueComponent from '@/js/tiptap-node-extension.js'


const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        TextAlign.configure({ types: ['heading', 'paragraph'] }),
        Underline,
        Link,
        VueComponent.extend({
                name: 'vueComponent',
                group: 'block',
                draggable: true,
                addAttributes() {
                    return {
                        src: {
                            default: '123',
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        ),
    ],
    content: props.modelValue,
    onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
        emit('update:modelValue', editor.getHTML())
    },
    editable: props.locked ? false : store.admin
})

const sendDataToExtension = async (editor, event) => {
    // Triggered upon event

    ...

    state.src = '123'
    editor.chain().focus().insertContent('<vue-component/>').run()
}
</script>
```

and the `vue component`:

```
<script setup>
import {NodeViewWrapper} from '@tiptap/vue-3'

const props = defineProps({
    node: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    updateAttributes: {
        type: Function,
        required: true,
    }
})

</script>


<template>
  <node-view-wrapper class="vue-component" data-drag-handle="">
    <p>{{ node.attrs.src }}</p>
  </node-view-wrapper>
</template>
```

The `default` of `src` gets through but when I try to assign a reactive object (that gets created after mounting the `editor` component) it ends up being `undefined`.

This works:

```
src: {
    default: '123'
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
...

src: {
    default: state.src
}

...

const sendDataToExtension = async (editor, event) => {
    // triggered upon event

    ...

    state.src = '123'
    editor.chain().focus().insertContent('<vue-component/>').run()

}
```

How do I send data to the `vue component` that is created after mounting `editor`?

Attempt:

```
editor.chain().focus().insertContent('<vue-component/>', {src: state.src}).run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would say that I would recommend creating a purpose built extension, instead of having the general `VueComponent` that you have now. If you extend more based on that extension you will have several extension competing for the  tag. Move all code that you set in extend to the actual extentions, you can set any tag-name you want.

Now to what I believe is the problem here: `insertContent` look like this:

```js
insertContent: (value: Content, options?: {
    parseOptions?: ParseOptions;
    updateSelection?: boolean;
})
```

Content is declared as

```js
export declare type Content = HTMLContent | JSONContent | JSONContent[] | null;
export declare type HTMLContent = string;
export declare type JSONContent = {
    type?: string;
    attrs?: Record<string, any>;
    content?: JSONContent[];
    marks?: {
        type: string;
        attrs?: Record<string, any>;
        [key: string]: any;
    }[];
    text?: string;
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

In your case you will have to add the src attribute to your html string, however I would recommend using the `JSONContent` type in your case then:

```js
editor.chain().focus().insertContent({type: "vueComponent", attrs:{src: state.src}}).run()
```

Here the type is the name that you set of the component.

Hope this makes sense, the documentation on tiptap is kind of good as well https://tiptap.dev/guide/custom-extensions/#attributes
Let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: Hey, this works! Would you mind adding the `html` method to your answer as well for future visitors? ```editor.chain().focus().insertContent(`<vue-component src="${state.src}"/>`).run()```